# Time complexity of this for loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Could anyone explain me the time complexity of this method?

```
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(n) + 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

I'm not really good in this subject and tried to find out some info online but could't find any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

its On(1) - linear, as it its linearly proportional on i (or less due to early stopping from module check); this is typical for a one level for loop